# Date from week of year returning date not in week

Tags: ios, date, swift, dayofweek

I have come across a rather strange "bug". When getting a date for a week of a year using this method:

```
let dates = NSMutableArray()
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
cal.firstWeekday = 2
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "ww YYYY"
formatter.calendar = cal
let date = formatter.dateFromString(week as String)
println(date)
```

The string `week` is `52 2014`, so the expected date would be Monday December 22th, but instead it returns Saturday December 20th, at 23:00. First of all, I thought I'd handled the first day of week by setting the `firstWeekday`-option of the calendar, but no luck. In addition, the date returned isn't even in week 52.

Just to double check I ran `cal.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYearCalendarUnit, fromDate: date!).weekOfYear` to double check I'm not an idiot, and no sir, the week for the date produced is 51, the week before the desired week.

Any idea how I can reach the expected result?

Comment: `YYYY` is probably the wrong formatter for you, as it is the year in the "Week of Year" calendar. This calendar is working with weeks. most of the time it is identically to the calendar we know from our everyday life, but at the beginning and end of a year it can yield stranger results: there first 3 days of January can be in a 53rd week of the last year or the last 3 days of December in the 1st week of the next year. You probably want to use `yyyy`.

Comment: And to people downvoting, please leave a comment explaining why this question isn't a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the firstWeekday from 1 to 2 won't change the date, it will change just the First weekday from Sunday to Monday.

You can do it like this:

```
func dateFromWeekOfYear(year:Int, weekOfYear:Int, weekday:Int) -> NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, yearForWeekOfYear: year, weekOfYear: weekOfYear, weekday: weekday, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
}

let date1 = dateFromWeekOfYear(2014, 52, 1)   // Dec 21, 2014, 12:00 AM
let date2 = dateFromWeekOfYear(2014, 52, 2)   // Dec 22, 2014, 12:00 AM
let date3 = dateFromWeekOfYear(2014, 52, 3)   // Dec 23, 2014, 12:00 AM
```

If dealing with a string and you want to set he Stand Alone local day of week you can do it like this:

```
let myDate = "2 52 2014"
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "c ww Y"
formatter.calendar = cal
if let date1 = formatter.dateFromString(myDate) {
    date1  // "Dec 22, 2014, 12:00 AM"
}
```

If you need further reference you can use this:

[image]

Comment: This is super helpful! I think I know where my logic fails, or the Calendar's logic rather, it doesn't care what day I set as the firstWeekday, it always counts the first Sunday (in this case Dec. 21st) as the Sunday of that particular week. So if for instance I'm looking for the Monday and Sunday of week 52 of 2014, and I use the formatter-method, it'll give me the 21st and 22nd of Dec.

Comment: HOWEVER, using your function, only with the calendar that has the firstWeekday-property set to 2, I get the expected result of 22nd and 28th of Dec. It seems like the formatter simply doesn't care about the calendar it's supposed to use. Strange, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea how I can reach the expected result?

What actually is your desired result? Do you want to know the first day of the week or the first day in the last day? Than you could tray this:

```
let now = NSDate()
var startDate: NSDate? = nil
var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0

let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
cal.firstWeekday = 2

cal.rangeOfUnit(.WeekCalendarUnit, startDate: &startDate, interval: &duration, forDate: now);


let endDate = startDate?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(duration)
print(startDate)
print(endDate)
```

it prints

```
"Optional(2014-12-21 23:00:00 +0000)"
"Optional(2014-12-28 23:00:00 +0000)"
```

the endDate is the first second that is not in the week anymore.

Note that the offset of 1 hour results from the fact that it is printed in UTC time, that is actually GMT winter time. Indeed these dates are `2014-12-22 00:00:00` and `2014-12-29 00:00:00` in my time zone (GMT+1)

---

or simply

```
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.weekOfYear = 52
components.weekday = 2
components.year = 2014

let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()    
let day = cal.dateFromComponents(components)
```

This code adapted to respect user's calendar:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.weekOfYear = 52
components.weekday = cal.firstWeekday
components.year = 2014
```

Comment: I actually tried your first example first, but I found that gave me unexpected results as well, and it would be of no use if I didn't get the actual first day of the week, which is the case. In addition, simply using the current date also gives two dates not even in the same week, proved by `println(cal.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYearCalendarUnit, fromDate: startDate!).weekOfYear)` and `println(cal.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYearCalendarUnit, fromDate: endDate!).weekOfYear)` returning 52 and 1.

Comment: They give the right results. all my examples. But it seems you don't know the basics of calendar calculations. you don't get the nature of NSDate being a point in time, expressed in UTC time. you seem to forget about time zones.

Comment: I do get it though, it's just that it contradicts itself by returning dates not in the same week, when checked against the same calendars WeekOfYear from the dates.

Comment: the dates are in the same week. you just don't understand dates's description.