# What is happening to the year?

Tags: date, swift

Putting this into a playground yields outputs that I don't understand.
The first output of `Dec 30, 2014` makes sense, however the 2nd `Dec 2015` doesn't.

Why is my 2nd output showing a year of 2015? My locale is the US with the Gregorian calendar.

```
import UIKit

let dateString = "2014-12-30T00:00:00.000-05:00"
let _dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
_dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
_dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSZZZZZ"

let date = _dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!

let format = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("MMM d YYYY", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = format
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle


let monthFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("MMM YYYY", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
let monthFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
monthFormatter.dateFormat = monthFormat

let fullDate = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
let monthDate = monthFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong string format. You have to change "Y" which is for Week of Year. Just change it to "y":

```
let dateString = "2014-12-30T00:00:00.000-05:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
 
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(date)  // "2014-12-30 05:00:00 +0000\n"
    
    dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMMd")
    let fullDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(fullDate)   // "Dec 30, 2014\n"
    
    dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMM")
    let monthDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(monthDate)  // "Dec 2014\n"
}
```

If you need some reference just take a look at this chart:

[image]

Comment: But why doesn't the first example then also print 2015 in the original code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651727/date-from-week-of-year-returning-date-not-in-week/27652083#27652083

Comment: Nothing but it will use it as Y